# Check font is only bold not extrabold, semibold or any ohter bold

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swiftui

i'm using `font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitBold)` but this function is returns true if font is `semibold`, `extra bold` or any other bold type.

i need solution for i have bold font then get true and i have `semibold`, `extra bold` or any other bold then get false.

Comment: Please choose tags wisely. What platform you are using ? web or iOS

Comment: my platform is iOS

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
let attributes = font.fontDescriptor.fontAttributes
let traits = attributes[.traits] as? [UIFontDescriptor.TraitKey : Any]
let weight = traits[.weight] as? UIFont.Weight
```

Then, you can compare the weight to `.bold`.

Comment: this code is not work because attributes contains only two value 1  NSFontSizeAttribute and 2 NSFontNameAttribute so every time gating traits is nil.

Comment: Does `font.fontDescriptor.object(forKey:.traits)` work better?

Comment: font.fontDescriptor.object(forKey:.traits) this way is some times work and some times not work.